# I want to change my website language into arabic using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to change my website language into arbic and I'm using the codeigniter framework. Currently when the language is getting changed it redirects to the index page whenever I click on langugage. But I want to redirect to the current web page where I'm clicking the language button.

Here is my controller file:

```
class Home extends CI_Controller {

    private $language = 'en';

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('B2C_model', 'B2C');
        $this->load->model('User_model', 'user');
        $this->load->model('Booking_model', 'booking');
        $this->load->library('PayOne');

        $language = $this->_getLanguage();

        if ($this->input->get('lang')) {
            set_cookie('language', $this->input->get('lang'), 86400);
            $language = $this->input->get('lang');
        }

        $this->language = $language;

        //$this->_getLanguage():
    }

    public function _getLanguage() {
        $language = $this->language;

        if (isset($_COOKIE['language'])) {
            $language = $_COOKIE['language'];
        }

        return $language;
    }

    // ========== Home Page =========== //

    public function index() {
        $data['language'] = $this->language;
        $data['cities'] = $this->B2C->cities();

        $data['title'] = 'Home';
        $data['mainContent'] = 'index';
        $this->load->view('layout/master', $data);
    }
```

Here is my header file:

```
<?php if($language == 'en'): ?>
    <a href="/?lang=ar"><button class="head-btn"><i class="fa fa-language" aria-hidden="true"></i> النسخة العربية</button></a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand **i18n** workflow. In CodeIgniter you have a *lang* helper who translated the key you pass into the language selected (check the *application/config/config.php*).

```
$config['language'] = 'en';
```

You need to dynamically change the language based on client (I guess). So, the next step you just call every string that will be printed to client using the *lang* helper. e.g.:

View:

```
<h2><?php echo lang("welcome"); ?></h2>
```

In Controller (construct) load the library (or use the [autoload](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/autoloader.html?highlight=autoload)):

```
$this->load->helper('language');
```

Source: [CI docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/language_helper.html?highlight=lang#lang)